# Can I call console app exe from asp.net with 2 argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I can call the console app from the asp.net web forms but if I have input one by one like below once I got the first argument from user input then they have another input please enter another number then user need to input another argument in console app. I have 2 arguments but both will take one by one. If single argument at first time then I can pass as below but with 2 I could not. How this possible If some one help then that would be good. I want to pass both argument.

### Asp.net web form

```
Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleEx.exe";   // actual file name
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "1 ";
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p1.Start();
            p1.WaitForExit();
            if (p1.HasExited)
            {
                string output = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                lblConsoleOutput.Text = output;

                p1.Dispose();
            }
```

### Console App

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1, num2;
        int add, sub, mul;
        float div;
        Console.Write("Enter 1st number\t");
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\nEnter 2nd number\t");
        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());}
```

Here is the image [image]

Comment: Do you control the console app? It's currently not using its command line arguments at all, but reading data *from the console*. While you *can* work with that within your ASP.NET app, it would be a lot cleaner if the console app just used the command line arguments. Alternatively, can you just invoke the `Main` method directly within your ASP.NET app, and not start another process?

Comment: Given the console doesn't *appear* to give any information back after the first argument why not just prompt the user to enter both parameters from the web interface UI then pass both to the console app?

Comment: Hi Jon & Jeames I have one console app that will take one by one input and take the out put you can see above image. I want to call this from asp.net web form and display the out put on web form.

Comment: @TusharMaru I don't see why the console app needs to take the parameters 1-by-1, if the purpose of the console app is purely to do the number crunching behind the scenes (and you have written it) then I would suggest you have it support passing *all* the numbers at once. This would allow you to prompt the user via the *web* interface for the numbers but behind the scenes pass all the accumulated numbers to the console app in one go.

Comment: Hi James, That is the issue the app is old dos app and we do not have source code. This is just a sample app actual app has different logic behind the scene and that is working like this. So I am finding the solution that we can pass param from web UI to console app there are lots of parameters one by one not all together in that console app.

Comment: Hi James, Can you help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the standard input and stream the values by code.

You can find an example here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I would suggest you to change the link to point to [English version of MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx).